# Blocked out of editing posts

Tags: support, suggested-edits

Some times when I'm editing people's posts and go to submit my edit for review, it says this page you've requested is no longer available. When I go back to edit, I'm unable to gain access. I've read other posts about making bad edits. But that isn't it.

I'm guessing this is because someone who has a higher editing authority has chosen to edit that post or something. This is extremely aggravating when I've spent time to format someone's post.

Is this what's happening? and
Is there anyway around this?

Comment: Your name is awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that someone has submitted a modification to the edit before you submitted your edit, in which case invalidating your edit. Cause well what you were editing isn't there anymore. You can always hit Ctrl-C Ctrl-A before hitting submit in case someone edits it before you submit your edit.

Im guilty of posting things and then realizing that i don't make any sense and editing it 2-3 minutes later. Adding Latex can take alot longer then correcting spelling etc.

Comment: What does Ctrl-C Ctrl-A do?

Comment: Ctrl-A selects all, Ctrl-C copies it.  So do it in that order, not Peter's order.

Comment: Thanks, @GEdgar.